# Create style from code behind

Tags: silverlight-4.0

in my silverlight application i want to create a style from code behind and apply created style to control. in database we have one table which is store a value like FontNaame ,Colour ,Bold ,Italic, Font Size i want to create a style base on that parameter and apply to control

is their any possibility?

please add code if it is possible

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
      // sampleText is the control to apply the style to
      Style styl = new Style(sampleText.GetType());
      switch (str)
      {
        case "Bold":
          styl.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.ExtraBold));
          break;
        case "Italic":
          styl.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic));
          break;
      }
      sampleText.Style = styl;
```

Simple sample project is here: http://sdrv.ms/MWPxuO